# Using Primefaces 5, should I be able to *dynamically* build a simple p:menu containing only menuitems? ...i.e., without submenu(s)?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

**QUESTION:** Using Primefaces 5, can I dynamically build a simple p:menu containing only menuitems - i.e., without submenu(s)?

For example,  I am able to successfully implement this static menu...

```
    -
    -
    -
    <h3>Static p:menu  (i.e., no submenus) - WORKING </h3>
    <p:menu id="menustatic">
        <p:menuitem value="operation1"  action="#{breadCrumb.navigate('page0')}" />
        <p:menuitem value="operation2"  action="#{breadCrumb.navigate('page1')}" />
        <p:menuitem value="operation3"  action="#{breadCrumb.navigate('page2')}" />
    </p:menu>
    -
    -
    -
```

But, when I attempt to implement the above menu dyamically from the managed bean, it is not working... i.e.,

the controller method

```
    -
    -
    -
    private DynamicMenuModel menuModel;
    public MenuModel getMenuModel()
    {
        menuModel = new DynamicMenuModel();

        DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
        item.setIcon("ui-icon ui-icon-newwin");
        item.setValue("operation1a");
        item.setCommand("#{breadCrumb.navigate('page0')}");
        menuModel.addElement(item);

        item = new DefaultMenuItem();
        item.setIcon("ui-icon ui-icon-newwin");
        item.setValue("operation1b");
        item.setCommand("#{breadCrumb.navigate('page1')}");
        menuModel.addElement(item);

        item = new DefaultMenuItem();
        item.setIcon("ui-icon ui-icon-newwin");
        item.setValue("operation1c");
        item.setCommand("#{breadCrumb.navigate('page2')}");
        menuModel.addElement(item);

        return menuModel;
    }
    -
    -
    -
```

the page/tag

```
    <h3>Dyamic p:menu  (i.e., no submenus) -  NOT WORKING </h3>
    <p:menu id="menudynamic" model="#{menuController.menuModel}" />
```

When I click on the "dynamically" built menu's menuitems I receive this error on my console...

```
    <Jul 17, 2014 1:12:52 PM EDT> <Warning> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle> <BEA-000000> <For input string: "null"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
        at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.findMenuitem(BaseMenuRenderer.java:83)
        at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.decode(BaseMenuRenderer.java:61)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    >
```

*Is the problem that I am simply misusing the "p:menu" tag in the first place, when I build the static version?... 
- Is this why my attempting to build a dynamic version of the same menu does not work as I would expect?*

Thanks for any help!

:)

Comment: Turns out that you CAN create "p:menu" without using "p:submenu"...   found my dynamic "p:menu" did not work unless the MenuModel was initialized in the managed bean's constructor.

Comment: i.e., ...vs.  instantiating the MenuModel and initializing it within the called method.  Dont know why yet - have to RTFM, etc

Comment: had any luck finding the proper solution? initializing in constructor is no option for me because it chages during session

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and solved it by setting a numerical id for every MenuItem.
e.g. `item.setId("1");`

Maybe it helps for you, too....

Comment: Ok this semed to work but only if i start the index with 0. Otherwhise the wron action was called when clicking the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `generateUniqueIds()` on your MenuModel after all MenuElements are added.